# Undefined variable in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have been getting this error Undefined variable nik when I want to access the array from for each this array getting information from the database

**View**

```
foreach ($data as $user) {
  $id_user = $user->id_user;
  $nama = $user->nama;
  $nik = $user->nik;
  echo $nik;
  $alamat = $user->alamat;
  $no_telp = $user->no_telp;
  $pass = md5($user->password);
  $name = $user->name;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_akun_detail() {
  $id_user = $this->input->get('id');
  $detail['data'] = $this->Madmin->user_akun_detail($id_user);
  $this->load->view('admin/Detail_user_pemilih', $detail);
  $this->session->set_flashdata('id_user', $id_user);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function user_akun_detail($id_user) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('akun');
  $this->db->join('detail_user', 'detail_user.id_user = akun.id_user');
  $this->db->join('image_user', 'akun.id_user = image_user.id_user');
  $this->db->where('akun.id_user', $id_user);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Read How to Ask a good question.

Comment: Well, apparently `$user` doesn't have a property called "nik".

Comment: yeah maybe your table 'akun, detail_user, image_user' does not have field called 'nik' .

Comment: On an unrelated note... Don't use MD5 for passwords.